# How to properly reuse a Provider in Flutter when i push another screen

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider, state-management

I have the exact same problem as it was described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60299247/how-to-properly-reuse-a-provider-in-flutter) , but i would like to reuse the provider in a pushed screen. For example: if i have the ChangeNotifierProvider wrapping the screenA, and then i push from screenA to screenB using Navigator.of(context).push..., i would like to acess the provider on the screenB without having to pass it as an argument. I am not able to do it as the answer said on the last question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: move the provider above the MaterialApp, after that you can access the provider from screenA, B, C or etc any where from application without having to pass it as an argument

```
void main() => runApp(
  ChangeNotifierProvider(
    create: (_) => YourProvider(),
    child: MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData.light(),
      home: Home()
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: this really worked, thanks. But why this happens?, and if there is a situation where i need to pass the provider through ScreenA pushed to ScreeB, and only wrap the ScreenA ? is there a good solution, or i have to pass it by the constructors?